# Is there a way to get a range from an ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

I would like to get a range from an ObservableCollection for the purpose of looping through it and changing a property on those items. Is there an easy built-in way to do this with the ObservableCollection class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Skip` and `Take`.

```
System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<int> coll = 
    new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<int>()
        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
foreach (var i in coll.Skip(2).Take(2))
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly the sort of thing I was looking for

Answer (score 4):

For looping, [`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) derives from `Collection<T>`, and implements `IList<T>`.  This lets you loop by index:

```
for (int i=5;i<10;++i)
{
     DoSomething(observableCollection[i]);
}
```

If you want to do queries on the collection via LINQ, you have a couple of options.  You can use [Skip()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) and [Take()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx), or build a new range and access by index:

```
var range = Enumerable.Range(5, 5);
var results = range.Select(i => DoMappingOperation(observableCollection[i]));
```

Or:

```
var results = observableCollection.Skip(5).Take(5).Select(c => DoMappingOperation(c));
```

Answer (score 1):

`ObservableCollection<T>` implements `Colletion<T>` which implements `IEnumerable` so you should be able to do (if you're looking for a range that matches a given criteria):

```
foreach(var item in observerableCollection.Where(i => i.prop == someVal))
{
    item.PropertyToChange = newValue;
}
```

Or an arbitrary range (in this case it takes items 10 - 40):

```
foreach(var item in observableCollection.Skip(10).Take(30))
{
    item.PropertyToChange = newValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(var item in MyObservableProperty.Skip(10).Take(20))
{
  item.Value = "Second ten";
}
```

[Skip](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CBMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fbb358985.aspx&ei=1yLUTNDkM8SblgflgpS9BQ&usg=AFQjCNGWbFG25BRoKRV1M_0IRruCVgbLaw) and [Take](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBYQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fbb503062.aspx&ei=7SLUTKzjKcL7lwe32JSRBQ&usg=AFQjCNHdOrPitywW78nbI8GqqpQjuj3KMQ) are linq extension methods used for paging a collection.

Comment: +1 for links, but accepting other answer since it was posted first. Thanks

Comment: @Rach I swear I started typing first!  Meeeeee!

Comment: lol what do you need 15 more rep from?? You already have 33k!

Comment: @Rach I need to catch up to [Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)